# Android - TabLayout inside a Fragment pin on top when scrolling up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

I have tried the combination of `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, which doesn't work for this situation. It seems that it only works for a main activity layout. Is it possible to pin the tab layout when scrolling up when it comes to the tab layout which is inside Fragment C? Thanks for your help.

This is a Fragment consisting of Fragment A, Fragment B, Fragment C, Fragment C contains a view pager and tab layout.

[image]

Finally, I would like to pin the tab layout on top of the screen when scrolling up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use StickyScrollView https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems

```
<com.kiwkard.views.StickyScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sticky_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout 
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/white"
          android:orientation="vertical"
android:tag="sticky-nonconstant">


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/black_30"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager_event"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</com.kiwkard.views.StickyScrollView>
```

don't forget to give `tag` attribute in your layout which you want to be fixed, and you can go through to above mentioned link for more tags according to your requirement.